# "py.test" vs "pytest" command

Tags: python, flask, python-import, pytest

The `py.test` command is failing in my case, whereas `pytest` is running totally fine.

I use the pytest-flask plugin:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/sebastian/develop/py/flask-rest-template, inifile: 
plugins: flask-0.10.0
```

When I invoke `$ py.test` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 301, in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
KeyError: local('/home/sebastian/develop/py/flask-rest-template')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 332, in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[conftestpath]
KeyError: local('/home/sebastian/develop/py/flask-rest-template/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 338, in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 650, in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 207, in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
  File "/home/sebastian/develop/py/flask-rest-template/conftest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.app import create_app
  File "/home/sebastian/develop/py/flask-rest-template/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
ERROR: could not load /home/sebastian/develop/py/flask-rest-template/conftest.py
```

This is my actual `conftest.py` file:

```
import pytest
from app.app import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

My project structure is as like:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── config.py   # flask configuration objects
├── conftest.py     # pytest configruation
├── requirements.txt
├── ...
└── tests
    └── ...
```

**So, what is the difference between the two commands? And why is one failing and the other not?**

---

update 1

1) I had to change my relative imports `from .config import Config` or `from config import Config` to absolute ones like `from app.config import Config`

2) Running flask with `python3 -m app.app`

3) now `pytest` and `py.test` work normal

Thank you very much for your help, folks!

---

update 2

This is getting weird... when using absolute imports, running python with the `-m` option and flask with `debug=True` then the `werkzeug` library is not reloading the sources as expected:

http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2015/06/12/flask-werkzeug-reloader-python-dash-m.html

https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/461

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1246

This helped me in my `app/app.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Then `python -m app.app` works fine.

Comment: `pytest` command is the [new](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1629) way, and you likely have an old version of pytest hanging around.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! So I'll only use `pytest` in the future...

Comment: What do `which pytest` and `which py.test` say?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/py.test` and 
`/usr/local/bin/pytest`. Both come with `pytest-3.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`  when I install like `sudo pip3 install pytest`.

Comment: Ha! Its about relative imports... When I do `from .config import Config` then `pytest` is running fine. But when importing like `from config import Config` than it fails...

Comment: But in order to run the app `python app/app.py` I need `from config import Config`. How can I make both working (running flask and pytest)?

Comment: But it even does not work with `pip install -e .` or `pip3 install -e .` ...

Comment: Hmm sry... I dont get it right. When I do `from app.config import Config` I get `ImportError: No module named 'app.config'; 'app' is not a package`.

Comment: `app` does not get recognized as package, although it contains a `__init__.py`

Comment: Thanks you all for your help! I've got it... so I really have to run it always like this: `python3 -m app.app` as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3#16985066. So with absolute imports like this `from app.config import Config` than also `py.test` works just fine.

Comment: I use `python3 -u -m pytest --color=auto` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

To answer the question about the actual command (meaning the invocation of the tool on the command line) in a bit more detail:

The `py.test` invocation is the old and busted joint. `pytest` is the new hotness (since 3.0). `py.test` and `pytest` invocations will coexist for a long time I guess, but at some point `py.test` might be deprecated. So I would recommend to [#dropthedot](https://twitter.com/davehunt82/status/756080181085872129).

> [...] so from pytest 3.0 we will supported and recommend use of pytest as the main command instead of py.test. It's possible that in future we will deprecate py.test and potentially even remove it.

-- [Dave Hunt](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1629#issue-161422224)

Backwards compatibility is a very important concern for the pytest community, so the old way might never go away and it's not much of a maintenance burden to keep it anyway (it is just defined as a different entry point in [setup.py](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/3.0.0/setup.py#L73)).

Comment: But at least showing a warning would have been way more useful, currently some errors don't happen when pytest is used while they do with py.test which is quite confusing if one is not aware of the deprecation of the py.test

Comment: @aderchox I am not aware of such a problem and I am not sure how they could behave differently (look at the link to `setup.py` in my answer - it is literally two different names for exactly the same thing). If you really found a problem there and it is reproducable, please open an issue on the pytest issue tracker.

Answer (score 8):

Use `pytest ...` or even better the `python -m pytest ...`.

You can forget about the old name, it's clearly a bug if you still spot it somewhere.